# How to verify if a node that might either contain a null or a string in the response body using Postman?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, postman, chai

I need to verify whether a particular node in the response body of an API is null or a string. How is it done using ChaiJS in postman tests?

Sample API response body:

```
[
 {
   "exercise_num": "1",
   "expire_date": "2019-03-11T16:31:17.935Z",
   "created_at": "2019-03-15T11:44:35.698Z"
 },
 {
    "exercise_num": "2",
    "expire_date": null,
    "created_at": "2019-03-15T11:44:38.363Z"
 }
]
```

I would like to verify that the expire_date node in the above sample API response body will either only contain null or a string data type and it won't return any other data type such as int, etc.

I have tried the following:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.test('All expire_date contains either string or null', () => {
for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
if(jsonData[i].expire_date === null){
tests["expire_date is null"] = true;
}
else{
    pm.expect(jsonData[i].expire_date).to.be.a('string');
}
}
});
```

The test passes.

I'm expecting if something like this can be done:

```
pm.test('All expire_date contains string', () => {
for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    pm.expect(jsonData[i].expire_date).to.be.a('string' || null);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no direct way with `||` operator though, you can check with data types. As `null` is an `object` type in javaScript, write the test case as follows:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

pm.test('All expire_date contains string', () => {

    for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {            
        pm.expect(typeof jsonData[i].expire_date).to.be.oneOf(['string', 'object']);
    }
});
```

That's probably an easy way, and can be used in simple checks. However, I'd recommend you to use the second way, i.e. using The fastest JSON Schema Validator.

```
var Ajv = require('ajv'),
ajv = new Ajv({logger: console}),
schema = {
    "properties": {
        "expireDate": {
            "type": ["string","null"]
        }
    }
};

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

pm.test('All expire_date contains string', function() {
    for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        pm.expect(ajv.validate(schema, {expireDate: jsonData[i].expire_date})).to.be.true;
    }
});
```

If you'd like you check this in multiple requests, put schema at collection level.

Comment: I tried using the 2nd way but postman throws the following error:
There was an error in evaluating the test script:  Error: Cannot find module 'ajv'

Comment: @NoorYeaserKhan: Check with the same version, can you try to downgrade version to v`6.7.4`?

Comment: I don't know what happened earlier. Now it's working fine with v.7.0.7. So thank you very much for your answer.